# Deploying to user page with gh-pages throws a fatal: A branch named 'master' already exists

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy my React webpage to the GitHub user level hosting so that the homepage url doesn't end up having any extra paths. In other words I want the url to be just **[username].github.io**

I've been following the [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages) documentation, and the part that talks about deploying to the GitHub user page has this snippet:

```
"scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
-   "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
+   "deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build",
```

when I try to run `npm run deploy` at the final stage of the compilation
I get the 
`fatal: A branch named 'master' already exists.`
error

I haven't encountered any issues hosting it on a project level (**[username].github.io/[repository_name]**) but I keep coming up short with this particular setup

Comment: Just manually deleting the folder node_modules/.cache/gh-pages

Comment: Why do you want to deploy the site to `master` instead of the default `gh-pages` branch?

Comment: Thank you @GuneshShanbhag that did the trick, I was stuck troubleshooting this for way too long

Comment: @Konrad I need to submit the page to an auto QA that only works with ```/``` being the root url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a cache issue.
Just manually delete the folder node_modules/.cache/gh-pages.
and deploy again.